# want to add all ages if objects were dynamic

Tags: javascript, recursion

this is persons object how can I add all ages in here if the object were dynamic. I tried to do it with recursion but not succeded any body can help , I tried to achieve it by reduce method of javascript but can't get the logic how to return value and add continuously to get result

```
enter code here
```

```js
const persons = {
  name: "Tom",
  age: 70,
  kids: [
    {
      name: "Jerry",
      age: 40,
      kids: [
        {
          name: "Jack",
          age: 10,
          kids: [
            {
              name: "take",
              age: 10,
            },
            {
              name: "Note",
              age: 5,
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          name: "atleast",
          age: 5,
        },
      ],
    },
   
  ],
};


here is my code 

let sum = 0;
const red = (arr) => {
  sum += arr.reduce((total, b) => {
    if (b.kids) {
      red(b.kids);
    }
    return total + b.age;
  }, sum);
  console.log(sum);
};
red(persons.kids);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple approach:

```js
const addAges = (person) => 
  person .age + (person .kids || []) .map (addAges) .reduce ((a, b) => a + b, 0)
```

I think this is a bit cleaner if we destructure the input:

```js
const addAges = ({age, kids = []}) => 
  age + kids .map (addAges) .reduce ((a, b) => a + b, 0)
```

And here it's still better if we extract a `sum` helper function, leading to a version I like:

```js
const sum = (ns) => 
  ns .reduce ((a, b) => a + b, 0)

const addAges = ({age, kids = []}) => 
  age + sum (kids .map (addAges))

const persons = {name: "Tom", age: 70, kids: [{name: "Jerry", age: 40, kids: [{name: "Jack", age: 10, kids: [{name: "take", age: 10}, {name: "Note", age: 5}]}, {name: "atleast", age: 5}]}]}

console .log (addAges (persons))
```

So `addAges` is a recursive function  we call it for each entry of our `kids` array, and it will return their nested sums.  Then we total the results with our value to get our final result.  The base case is just when there are no `kids`, and we will end up with only the age of our person.